# Error while installing wget and unzip

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, debian-installer

I am trying to install wget and unzip on an Ubuntu machine. But I am facing the issue shown in the screenshot (dependency problems).

```
sudo apt-get install wget unzip
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Catch 22 you're in. You're trying to install something python-related that was made for **Python v2**, not 3, but the default version used and installed on your system IS v3. The module mentioned is now called `configparser` in Python 3, whilst it was called `ConfigParser` in Python 2. As we're on an OS where case sensitivity is very important, the compiler will treat these as two entirely different things.
So should you have both v2 and v3 installed, my strategy would be that you try to force the `pycompile` of v2 (if applicable).
The hackish solution would be that you *replace* every instance of `ConfigParser` by its v3-compliant counterpart `configparser`. However, be warned that this is not for the faint of heart...

In a nutshell:
What you're trying to install **does not support Python 3**.

Rule of thumb:
ABSOLUTELY make sure that whatever you install that is related to Python will be either for v2 or v3. These two versions are as different as the seasons summer and winter, which can be shown very easily by merely a short 20-line excerpt of a v2 script and its v3 update. It sometimes looks as a complete rewrite.